# Output file issues/ incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks

Making a payroll assignment in my intro to C class and the objective is to read a text file and then output their pay information to a text file. I've received some incompatible pointer errors and CodeBlocks is only giving me an output file which contains a bunch of gibberish. I posted the text file below with my comments so you can understand what I'm doing with my code. Any help will do, appreciate it guys and gals.

```
2 (this is the number of employees)
5.50 (pay rate for employee 0)
10.00 (pay rate of employee 1)
3 (number of weeks)
2 (data in relation to this week)
1 10 30 13 30 (reads: employee 1 clocked in at 1030, clocked out 1330)
0 7 0 16 30   (reads: employee 0 clocked in at 700, clocked out  1630)
4
0 9 0 14 30
1 7 0 23 0
1 9 0 22 0
1 7 20 23 20
3
0 10 0 15 0
1 8 0 12 0
0 9 30 11 30

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define EMPLOYEES 20
#define WEEKS 10

/*prototype functions: One to take in the total hours, the other printing out the text file*/
double totalHrs(int hi, int mi, int ho, int mo);
void printLog( int weeks, int numEmp, double Emp[numEmp][2], int wkHrs[numEmp][weeks]);

int main()
{

/*variables for number of employees, number of weeks, shifts and hours in and hour along with minutes.*/
int n, weeks, shifts;
int empId, hrIn, minIn, hrOut, minOut, tmpWkHrs;
double m;

FILE *ifp;

/*Read clock text file*/
ifp = fopen("clock.txt", "r");


    if(ifp == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
/*scan in the number of employees*/
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n);
if(n>EMPLOYEES)
{
    printf("Employees provided is greater than 20");
    exit(0);
}

double emp[n][2];
for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%lf", &m);
    emp[i][1] = m;
}

fscanf(ifp, "%d", &weeks);
double empWkHrs[n][weeks];

for(int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &shifts);

    for (int j = 0; j < shifts; j++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &empId);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &hrIn);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &minIn);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &hrOut);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &minOut);
        emp[empId][0] += totalHrs(hrIn, minIn, hrOut, minOut);
        empWkHrs[empId][i] += totalHrs(hrIn, minIn, hrOut, minOut);
    }
}

    printLog(weeks, n, emp, empWkHrs);
    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
double totalHrs(int hi, int mi, int ho, int mo)
{
    double totalHrs = (double)abs(ho - hi);
    double totalmins = (double)abs(mo - mi);
    totalHrs += totalmins/60;

    return totalHrs;

}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*Print function that prints out the information onto a text file named payroll*/
void printLog( int weeks, int numEmp, double Emp[numEmp][2], int wkHrs[numEmp][weeks])
{

    FILE *ofp;
    ofp = fopen("payroll.txt", "w+");

    if(ofp == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(ofp, "Number of employees: %d\n", numEmp);
    fprintf(ofp, "Number of weeks: %d\n", weeks);

/*Loop through to print out all of the information in regards to every week*/
    for(int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        fprintf(ofp, "Wk%d\n", weeks+1);
        fprintf(ofp,"EmpID\t Hours\t Pay\n");

        for(int j = 0; j < numEmp; j++)
        {
            /*If statement for an employee that works over 40 hours */
            if(wkHrs[j][i] > 40)
            {
                fprintf(ofp, "\t %d\t %lf\t %lf", j, wkHrs[j][i], (Emp[j][1]*40)+(wkHrs[j][i]-40)*1.5*Emp[j][1]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(ofp, "\t %d\t %lf\t %lf", j, wkHrs[j][i], Emp[j][1]*wkHrs[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(ofp, "Total\n");
    fprintf(ofp, "EmpID\t Hours\t Pay\n");

     for(int j = 0; j < numEmp; j++)
    {
        fprintf(ofp, "\t %d\t %lf\t %lf", j, Emp[j][0], Emp[j][1]*Emp[j][0]);
    }

    fclose(ofp);

}
```

This is what the output should look like.

```
Number of employees: 2
Number of weeks: 3
Wk 1
EmpID Hours Pay
 0 9.50 52.25
 1 3.00 30.00
Wk 2
EmpID Hours Pay
 0 5.50 30.25
 1 45.00 450.00
Wk 3
EmpID Hours Pay
 0 7.00 38.5.00
 1 4.00 40.00
Total
EmpID Hours Pay
 0 22.00 121.00
 1 52.00 520.00
```

This is what I get in my payroll.o file

```
Number of weeks: %d
Wk%d
EmpID    Hours   Pay
     %d  %lf     %lfTotal
qÄzRxê$@¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇAÜC
$D˚ˇˇˇˇˇˇqAÜC
$lp˚ˇˇˇˇˇˇAÜC
-c-
```

Comment: What were the "incompatible pointer errors" (which I suspect are compiler warnings since you have an executable)?

Comment: I was able to fix the incompatible errors, I am now just having issues with my output text file. CodeBlocks is only giving me a payroll.o file instead of a payroll.txt. When I open the .o file, it's just a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: Why would CodeBlocks give you a text file? It the program which does that after processing the input file. The .o file is an object file produced by the compiler.

Comment: Isn't the program writing to a text file in this part:


FILE *ofp;
    ofp = fopen("payroll.txt", "w+");

Comment: I don't follow all of what you are doing since you have not provided a MCVE that demonstrates the fault. But I can say that `totalHrs()` returns the wrong time interval. `hours = totalHrs(10, 59, 11, 01);` returns `1.966667` but the actual time interval is only 2 minutes, `0.033333` hours.

Comment: "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a what the output should look like and what my results show. I hope this clears anything up.

Answer (score 1):

In your `printLog` the last parameter should be of type `double`, not `int`.

Comment: Appreciate it very much, still need to figure out getting my output text file.